# Can't get the Python3 - MySQLdb connector to work in 16.04

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, ubuntu, mysql-python

I'm having trouble getting the python3-mysql connector to work properly in Ubuntu 16.04.

```
import MySQLdb as mdb
db_host = 'localhost'
db_user = 'sec_user'
db_pass = 'zygf'
db_name = 'securities_master'
con = mdb.connect(host=db_host,user=db_user, passwd=db_pass, db=db_name)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/tom/SAT/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 86, in Connect
return Connection(*args, **kwargs)


File "/home/tom/SAT/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 204, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'sec_user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)")
```

The chap here (who is clearly following the same tutorial I am) had a similar problem. He was able to resolve his problem my making sure his user had access to the correct database.

https://asyoulook.com/computers%20&%20internet/connecting-python-to-mysql-obtaining-sandamp-p500-symbols/603229

to set up my user I used:

```
mysql> CREATE DATABASE securities_master;
mysql> USE securities_master;

mysql> CREATE USER ’sec_user’@’localhost’ IDENTIFIED BY ’password’;
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON securities_master.* TO ’sec_user’@’localhost’;
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

which I believe is correct, but I am still getting the same error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bro you are creating the user correctly the problem is that you are giving sec_user in your code one password:

> db_pass = 'zygf'

and when you are creating the user you are setting a different password for sec_user:

> mysql> CREATE USER ’sec_user’@’localhost’ IDENTIFIED BY ’password’;

That way it'll never do the connection. You need both (the db_pass and the sql have the same password). So I will fix it changing the password of the sql to the one you have on your python code (zygf).

First: Delete the sec_user. Use this:

```
DROP USER 'sec_user'@'localhost';
```

Second: Create sec_user again using this (fixed the password):

```
mysql> CREATE USER ’sec_user’@’localhost’ IDENTIFIED BY ’zygf’;
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON securities_master.* TO ’sec_user’@’localhost’;
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```